# the markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I am getting the below error for GWT UI: UiBinder parser
the referenced file contains error (http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent)

**Show Details:** the markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed in GWT UI: UiBinder

**Error:** `<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the file is ill-formed, so the error is expected. Don't use it, find another one (for example https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent, others are linked from https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1)

I'd suggest reporting the issue to the GWT project so Google can fix it (or removing it)